# Rebuilding Reporting Database Sitecore 8

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

Whenever I try to run the reporting database rebuild I get the error "Exceeded the cut off date before clearing storage". Has anyone experienced this or know what it means?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, to work through this make sure you attach a clean reporting database. Next, make sure that the SQL user account has the db_owner role for both reporting databases. Lastly, and while not necessarily required, I prefer to purge everything from the sitecore_analytics_index folder (in your data\indexes folder).

Comment: Making the SQL user account has the db_owner role for both reporting databases worked otherwise it failed twice on "Clearing Storage" +1 for that.

Answer (score 3):

The other option is to change the `TimeToClearStorage` setting as per this Sitecore article: https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/80/xdb_configuration/walkthrough_rebuilding_the_reporting_database

Specifically:

> In the latest version of Sitecore xDB, the primary SQL Server reporting database contains some additional marketing definition tables that you need to copy to the secondary reporting database. When you run the rebuild reporting database page ensure that you allow more time for the clear storage process while these tables are being copied.
>
> The default time to clear storage setting is 1 minute. Change this setting to a time interval appropriate for your Sitecore solution, for example, 10 minutes.
>   To change the TimeToClearStorage setting:
>
> 1. Open the Sitecore.Analytics.Processing.Aggregation.config file.
> 2. Change the TimeToClearStorage setting to an appropriate time. For example 10 minutes.

```xml
<reportingStorageManagertype="Sitecore.Analytics.Aggregation.History.ReportingStorageManager"singleInstance="true">
  <TimeToClearStorage>0.00:01:00</TimeToClearStorage>
```

I set mine to 20 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

1) Like Marco said you can change TimeToClearStorage
2) Make sure db_owner role is there for secondary (primary usually have this)
3) Then this will go through.. but later if it pauses for WaitReadyToReceiveData then you might need to do some manual updations as [mentioned here](http://blog.ryanbailey.co.nz/2017/06/sitecore-reporting-database-rebuild-sql.html) . 
4) After some time you should see it in 'completed' status.